# Python ssh command to change user

Tags: python, ssh

I need to run a python script that will ssh to a remote host.  The first command to run on this remote host is "sudo su".  I have the password for it.  Then I need to cd to a directory and copy a file to my local box.  I tried in two ways.  Both of them don't work.

script #1:

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostName,username='e0258595',password='<password>')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo su; whoami")
stdin.write('password\n')
stdin.flush()
data = stdout.readlines()
for line in data:
    print line
```

The output is still e0258595.

Script #2:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostName, username="e0258595", password="<password>")
transport = ssh.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.set_combine_stderr(True)
session.get_pty()
#for testing purposes we want to force sudo to always to ask for password. because of that we use "-k" key
session.exec_command("sudo su; whoami")
stdin = session.makefile('wb', -1)
stdout = session.makefile('rb', -1)
#you have to check if you really need to send password here
stdin.write("<password>"+'\n')
stdin.flush()
data = stdout.readlines()
for line in data:
     print line
```

This one just hang.

What is the problem?

Comment: You should use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` for an interactive root shell.

Comment: Also, try sending one command at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using get_pty=True?

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo su; whoami", get_pty=True)
```